Magento Adobe Commerce + Live Search
I am using Live Search in my project, and the configuration has been completed. Live Search is now working perfectly on the site.
However, I need to update the data when syncing the product feed using the command:
bin/magento saas:resync --feed products

For example, I want to post my custom image URL during this process.
Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this or provide debugging pointers to help me work on it?
